# Copiar un archivo exe desde Recurso hacia la memoria RAM y ejecutarlo en Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi

Existe un ejemplo en esta página que lo hace bien en delphi 7 pero yo necesito que funcione en Delphi 10.3 Rio, por favor ayuda con esto, lo publique en stackoverflow en ingles, pero al parecer no entendieron mi pregunta.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Para próximas ocasiones estaría bien que dieras más datos ***del ejemplo que funciona*** y de ***porqué no funciona en versiones nuevas***.

El procedimiento que explicas es sencillo y debería funcionar igual para cualquier tipo de fichero, sea una imagen o una aplicación. Los pasos son los siguientes:

Primero debes creas un fichero de recursos (`RECURSOSVARIOS.RC`) como este:

```
// Recursos para imágenes
MINION          RT_IMAGE   ".\minion.jpg"
// Recurso para un EXE
DUMMYAPP        RT_RCDATA  ".\DummyApp.exe"
```

A continuación lo compilas con un CMD como este (`RC.CMD`):

```
brcc32 RecursosVarios.rc > Errores.txt
```

Eso genera un fichero `RECURSOSVARIOS.RES` que debes añadir a tu DPR con la siguiente línea:

```
{$R RecursosVarios.RES}
```

Para extraer los recursos del EXE y grabarlos en disco, se utiliza la clase `TResourceStream` y el código puede ser este:

```
var
  RecursoStream: TResourceStream;
  path:String;
begin
  // Para la imagen
  RecursoStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'MINION', 'RT_IMAGE');
  try
    RecursoStream.Position := 0;
    // Nombre del fichero destino
    path := IncludeTrailingBackslash(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)) + 'YourImage.jpg';
    RecursoStream.SaveToFile(path);
  finally
    RecursoStream.Free;
  end;
  // Cargarla en el form
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(path);

  // Para el EXE
  RecursoStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'DUMMYAPP', 'RT_RCDATA');
  try
    RecursoStream.Position := 0;
    path := IncludeTrailingBackslash(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)) + 'YourApp.exe';
    RecursoStream.SaveToFile(path);
  finally
    RecursoStream.Free;
  end;
  // ejecutar la aplicación
  ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(path), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
```

En ambos casos, se carga el recurso y se guarda en disco. 
Posteriormente la imagen se carga en un componente y la aplicación se ejecuta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ***NOTA IMPORTANTE:*** Ya te aviso que aunque el procedimiento funciona, como puedes ver, es posible que en muchos equipos tengas
>   problemas con anivirus y aplicaciones de seguridad.  Como es normal,
>   `"no suele gustarles"` a las suites de seguridad y programas similares,
>   que una aplicación (EXE) extraiga otro EXE de sus recursos, lo grabe en
>   disco y lo ejecute. Es bastante probable que bloqueen tu programa y
>   que borren el EXE del recurso al extraerlo y el EXE original; Que lo
>   marquen como virus e incluso que no puedas ni ejecutarlo (cosa por
>   otro lado bastante lógica).